# Changing the Angle of the Android StackView

Tags: android, stackview

Does anyone know of a way to change the **angle** of a StackView.  I'd love to be able angle a Stackview 45 degrees.

Thanks.

Comment: stackViewObj.setrotation(45); //set 45 or 135 according to your need

Comment: please marked as answer thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tackViewObj.setrotation(45); //set 45 or 135 according to your need